# How to test UIFontMetrics UIFont.TextStyle in XCTest

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, uifont

How can I test the given `UIFont.TextStyle` for a `UIFont` with a dynamic font size via `UIFontMetrics` in `XCTest` unit testing?

```swift
var myDynamicFont: UIFont {
    let font = UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: 42)
    return UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).scaledFont(for: font)
}
```

*XCTest Unit Test:*

```swift
func testMyDynamicFont() {
    ...
    XCTAssertEqual(myDynamicFont.???, .largeTitle) // <-- How to check the given TextStyle?
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Interesting question, but why you can't just compare your myDynamicFont and expected font? UIFont is Equatable so it looks like viable solution.

Comment: That's a viable way! I didn't saw that `UIFont` is `Equatable`. Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually UIFont is _not_ equatable in any useful way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SnapshotTesting](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing):

```
func test_myDynamicFont_matchesSnapshot() {
    assertSnapshot(matching: myDynamicFont, as: .dump)
}
```

Snapshot with .dump strategy will produce something like that:

```
- <UICTFont> font-family: ".SFUI-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 42.00pt
```

Or you can use your view to produce .image snapshot and match it:

```
func test_label_matchesSnapshot() {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "some text"
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.font = myDynamicFont
    assertSnapshot(matching: label, as: .image, record: true)
}
```

This will produce image snapshot:

[image]

and will match it every time you run tests.

Comment: Thank you @vsnv, but I would like to know, if it's possible with a native solution so that a third party library isn't needed for that specific case.

Comment: @SchmidtFx yep, i understand, mentioned this way in case that it maybe can help you in future.